# allow not working on new router using 10.0.0.1

Tags: nginx

i've just installed a new router that runs a different set of ip address and i cant seem to get nginx to allow devices on my network to access a site without basicauth.

the ip of my new router is 10.0.0.1
my sub net is .255.255.255.0

```
location /mylar {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
satisfy any;
  allow 10.0.0.1/24;

        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;
        }
```

could some please help me resolve this.

Comment: Put the line `deny all;` after `allow` directive.

Comment: i added that but it still doesnt bypass the basicauth edit: im also seeing this in the error logs............  2019/10/20 00:13:54 [warn] 11612#6960: low address bits of 10.0.0.1/24 are meaningless in C:\nginx-1.8.0/conf/nginx.conf:109

Comment: 1) i think this warning will gone if you change 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.0
2) this is a stupid question, but - your nginx server located inside your 10.0.0.1/24 subnet?

Comment: okay changed that but no change, yes it's on my pc that's on 10.0.0.8 also the error is still in the log

Comment: You could try adding `allow all` and check the logs to see what IP address Nginx is accepting the connection from. What error is still in the logfile? The "low address bits" after using `10.0.0.0/24`? Because that make no sense unless Nginx is reading a different file.